# How is the duration of effects measured in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Potions and certain items grant benefits like enhancing smithing or having increased health generation for a certain duration. How is this time measured? Is this clock time or in-game time? Does time spent in menus count against the given time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The duration for effects are all measured in clock time<sup>1</sup>.  The game time, by default, is set to a scale of 20, so 1 minute in real time is equivalent to 20 minutes in game time.

[This other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35869/what-actions-freeze-time) explains exactly what actions freeze the game time.

<sup>1</sup>Waiting and fast travel, despite not advancing much clock time, does count against the durations.

Comment: I always had problems with his in-game/real-life times also :) Do I understand correctly then: Enemy frozen for 60 seconds will then mean that he will be frozen for (only) 3 of my real-life seconds?

Comment: @LudoMC you have it the other way around.  If a potion says the effect will last 60 seconds, it will last 60 real time seconds, which is roughly equivalent to 20 in game minutes.

Comment: I knew I was always wrong with this :) Thanks for the clarification, makes far more sense this way. I'll start again making potions then!

Comment: It's worth noting that time pauses when talking to shopkeepers, but not when using a grindstone, forge, alchemy table, furnace, enchanting table, or anything where animation continues. This means you can take your time with a Potion of Fortify Barter, but need to hurry with your Potion of Fortify Smithing.

Comment: I didn't see it listed in related questions, but shrines that confer a blessing for 8 hours are 8 real hours. That's almost a week in Skyrim. The Gift of Charity lasts 60 real minutes, so that's the better part of a day in Skyrim. The rested bonuses are different. Those last for 8 in game hours, or 24 real minutes.